# onchange event for <div> element when I have no control over when it is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-events, onchange

I have a div element on a page that has other divs added to it when certain events happen. I do not know when these events happen, how they are triggered and how the other divs are added to the main div (its external so I have no idea whats happening all I have access to is the div).

How would I "monitor" for changes to the main div so an event is triggered whenever a new div is added ? I know I can use setInterval (which is what I'm doing now), but I really do not want to use it unless absoluley necessary. I would love to something as simple as form elements do with onchange but I have not found such for divs.

Example if text is not clear:

wesite.com/index.html ( the only thing I have access to)

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="theDiv">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and at times unknown to me divs get added to that div and it eventually looks like :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="theDiv">
        <div class="added"><p>Added Div</p></div>
        <div class="added"><p>Added Div</p></div>
        <div class="added"><p>Added Div</p></div>
        <div class="added"><p>Added Div</p></div>
        <div class="added"><p>Added Div</p></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And lets say I set up the event to trigger an alert, in this example I want to see an alert box every time a new div is added so by the time it looks like this I should have seen 5 alert boxes.

Sorry if this is difficult to follow..

Comment: Probably you have to check with the javascript you are using. Place the javascript code here. Unless you place the javascript code here we won't be able to say what the problem is?

Comment: There is no problem, so my code is irrelevant. I want to know of a different (better) way to do what I need to. What I am currently doing works fine, but I don't want to use setInterval I would like to be able to "be notified" of changes instead of me checking for changes.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to intercept the calls that are adding the children to the DIVs.  Is this not an option?

Comment: what do you mean by "intercept the calls" the divs are being added not by some event i am triggering but somewhere else, I only see the result (new div being added). Sorry if I seem new, I am (to javascript/web development anyway). Thanks.